# Extracting three distinct variables from one string with one static and one dynamic delimiter in Powershell

Tags: powershell, extract

I am given a list of items:

```
X\Y Z

X\Y Z

X\Y Z

X Z
```

The static delimiter is the space between X\Y or X and Z.

The dynamic delimiter is the '\', and it is "dynamic" in that, as in the fourth example, it might be there, it might not.

I'm trying to extract each item and assign it to a separate array. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post some code, or research you've done, and what didn't work.

Comment: `function readList { # Begins to read "X\Y Z" list
 
 $a = get-content "\\$server\d$\xyzlist.txt"
 
 new-item "\\$server\d$\xyztemp.txt" -type file -force
 
 $a
 
 foreach ($object in $a)
  {
   $c = $object -replace "\\", "``r"
   add-content "\\$server\d$\xyztemp.txt" $c
   $d = get-content "\\$server\d$\HostInstance.txt"
  }

 notepad \\$server\d$\HostInstance.txt
 start-sleep -seconds 3
 rm \\$server\d$\HostInstance.txt
 
}`

The below responses help me get to where I need to go assigning to an array, I can feel it. Just not sure how to do it yet.

Comment: HostInstance is original txt name... sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$list = 'X\Y Z','X\Y Z','X\Y Z','X Z'
$list | Foreach {$_.Split("\ ", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)}
```

Update: You can use a regex as well:

```
36> $pattern = '(?<x>\w+)(\\(?<y>\w+))?\s+(?<z>\w+)'
37> 'X\Y Z' -match $pattern
True
38> $matches.x
X
39> $matches.y
Y
40> $matches.z
Z
41> 'X Z' -match $pattern
True
42> $matches.x
X
43> $matches.y
44> $matches.z
Z
```

Comment: `$list | Foreach {$_.Split("\ ", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)}` worked for me as well as the one above, but same issue. Trying to populate into arrays so I can pass the values dynamically to functions that will be running - potentially - on more than 100 servers at a time. Is there a way to say, "What is to the left of the \ is X, to the right and before the space (if applicable) is Y, and to the right of the space is Z"?

Comment: Well, one way would be to look in $list[0] for X and if $list.Count is 3 then Y is at index 1 and Z is at index 2.  If $list.Count is 2 then Z is at index 2.  Another approach is to use regex. See updated answer.

Comment: Could you paste a favorite link for regex training?

Comment: Not training but this is one of the best books on regex IMO: http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-ebook/dp/B007I8S1X0/

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
$list = 'X\Y Z','X\Y Z','X\Y Z','X Z'
$list -split '\\| '
```

Comment: `$object -split '\\| '` worked in splitting them each out on separate lines. I assume that was the intent. I assume this splitting can be written directly into the arrays?

Comment: Same question as below @C.B. ...  Is there a way to say, "What is to the left of the \ is X, to the right and before the space (if applicable) is Y, and to the right of the space is Z"?